# How to make an Android Library available via build.gradle?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I made an android library that I'd like upload to make it available for all the android devs via build.gradle. I've followed [these steps](http://blog.glassdiary.com/post/67134169807/how-to-share-android-archive-library-aar-across) and [these steps](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/artifact_management.html), but this is the first time that I'm doing this and can't achieve it. I'd appreciate advices or instructions from some of you that already made it.

But I'm not even sure what do I have to do. I wanna make my library available for all the android developers by writing something like this in their build.gradle:

```
compile 'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried with the links the other answers suggested but I think the steps were not clear enough... so I couldn't make it work (I think I might be guilty as well for not understanding well enough).

Anyways, a couple months later I found [this super cool post](https://medium.com/@scottyab/how-to-publish-your-open-source-library-to-maven-central-5178d9579c5) that explains in detail and clear all the steps you have to follow in order to upload your open source library to maven and make it available via gradle. Thanks to the guys that answered before, hope this helps someone else like it helped me.

Comment: Thanks for the mention (i wrote the post), if you wanna save some hassle of maven it's even quicker to use http://jitpack.io

Comment: Thank YOU for writing that post! I gave up on uploading my library a couple of months ago, but then [Android Weekly](http://androidweekly.net/)  shared your post and I gave it a try, It helped me a lot :D

Answer (score 0):

Gradle Fetch the Dependency libraries from Maven Repository you have to upload the package to the [Maven Repo](http://search.maven.org/) or just put the library in the /libs folder and put this under dependencies block:

```
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
```

You can see a guide to upload a library to the maven repo [Here](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-central-repository-upload.html)

Answer (score 0):

Follow these instructions :
http://gmariotti.blogspot.in/2013/09/publish-aar-file-to-maven-central-with.html , 
https://github.com/chrisbanes/gradle-mvn-push