# How to publish an Android library to a Maven repository to be used easily?

Tags: android, maven, aar

I published my Android library (with dependencies) to an AWS S3 maven repository using [this](https://medium.com/@porten/publishing-android-library-artifacts-to-amazon-s3-buckets-8db4231e844f) guide.

In a new project, I added the S3 bucket as a Maven repository, and I can successfully use it if I add the following to the new project's build.gradle file:

```
implementation ('com.mydomain:my_library:1.4:release@aar') {
    transitive=true
}
```

("transitive=true" is required so that the library's dependencies are included.)

However, I'd like for others to be able to use a simplified version of that like I've seen so many other libraries do:

```
implementation 'com.mydomain:my_library:1.4'
```

When I do that, I get "Cannot resolve symbol" errors in code and (of course) get "does not exist" errors when I try to build my project.

My library's POM file is shown below. Is there something I can change there so I can use the "simplified" implementation line above, or is there something else I can do?

Note: I tried replacing "< packaging>pom< /packaging>" with "< packaging>aar< /packaging>", invalidated the cache, and ran again, but the behavior was identical.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.mydomain</groupId>
  <artifactId>my_library</artifactId>
  <version>1.4</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.android.support</groupId>
      <artifactId>appcompat-v7</artifactId>
      <version>27.1.1</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.android.support.constraint</groupId>
      <artifactId>constraint-layout</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.3</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.android.support</groupId>
      <artifactId>design</artifactId>
      <version>27.1.1</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.reactivex.rxjava2</groupId>
      <artifactId>rxandroid</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.0</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.reactivex.rxjava2</groupId>
      <artifactId>rxjava</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.4</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.github.instacart.truetime-android</groupId>
      <artifactId>library-extension-rx</artifactId>
      <version>3.3</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.dagger</groupId>
      <artifactId>dagger-android</artifactId>
      <version>2.15</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.nostra13.universalimageloader</groupId>
      <artifactId>universal-image-loader</artifactId>
      <version>1.9.5</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.firebase</groupId>
      <artifactId>firebase-core</artifactId>
      <version>16.0.6</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.firebase</groupId>
      <artifactId>firebase-messaging</artifactId>
      <version>17.3.4</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Answer (score 3):

If your project happens to be hosted on Github consider using https://jitpack.io/ instead.

Jitpack allows you to very easily publish your libraries to gradle directly from Github.

While this answer does not directly answer your question, it does offer a valid and simpler alternative.

Comment: thanks, bro, I spent literally a day trying to use bintray

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same issue! and asked the same question, you can see my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24767972/how-to-make-an-android-library-available-via-build-gradle). My problem was the explanations in the answers and the posts shared to me were not clear enough (or maybe I wasn't able to understand them properly)... BUT! then I found [this super useful post](https://medium.com/@scottyab/how-to-publish-your-open-source-library-to-maven-central-5178d9579c5) thanks to AndroidWeekly, I followed the steps in that post and then I was able to publish my library to maven, you can check my library in [here](https://github.com/amilcar-sr/JustifiedTextView) and you can add it to your project using this:

```
implementation 'com.codesgood:justifiedtextview:1.1.0'
```

Just the way you want to make yours available through gradle. Let me know if you need some help going through the steps of that post, I'll be happy to help

Comment: Thanks. I had seen that article before, but unfortunately it doesn't cover using an AWS S3 repository or explain how to eliminate "release", "@aar" or "transitive=true" when trying to use the library. However, it does link to another tutorial on using an S3 repository that I will check out. If you know how to get rid of rid of those elements (POM file changes?) I would be very interested!

Comment: I've been reading some blogs and other questions and it seems like the @aar notation turns off the transitive flag, because it means you wanna download just the aar artifact, and no the dependencies... check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31753839/3257814). So if you can remove the "@aar" notation, you should be good to go ✌

Comment: But seems like removing that @aar is exactly what you're struggling with... give me a few mins, I'll compare your POM with the one I used to upload my library, maybe I can find some important difference.

Comment: Seems like the only difference is the packaging I used "aar" instead of "pom", the rest is pretty much the same but because of the simplicity of my library (it's just a view that justifies the text contained in it) I didn't need any external dependencies... so maybe that's why I didn't find the problem you're seeing 

Comment: Yeah, changing to < packaging>aar< /packaging> in the POM file didn't seem to help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are building the library using maven, you need to add the maven android plugin. That way you can package it as an AAR file. In this case, in my experience, the compile scope does not spread your library's dependencies into the path, you still need to add the transitive=true flag.

plugin website: https://simpligility.github.io/android-maven-plugin/plugin-info.html

Example POM: https://github.com/fcopardo/EasyRest/blob/master/pom.xml

Now, if you are using gradle to create the library, you need to understand how gradle packages the dependencies. There are two ways:

implementation: by using this word, the dependency is kept into the library's path. It will not be exposed to the consumer's path. Therefore, the consumer project will fail if the library's dependency needs to be located. For example, if you are going to return RxAndroid observables, compiling will fail, since the compiler will not be able to locate the RxAndroid classes mentioned in the return's methods signature. In the other hand, if the library's dependency is used only internally (for example, you build a rest module using retrofit and expose only RxJava in the return signatures), compilation will be possible.

api: is the exact opposite of implementation. Dependencies labeled as api will creep into the consumer's path, therefore, it must be used everytime you are exposing one of your dependencies. Using the same example as before, you should import RxAndroid with api, and retrofit with implementation. That should allow you to consume the library without any extra imports or flags.

Keep in mind, the maven android plugin supports the gradle project's format since version 4, so you can have both a POM file and a .gradle file.